# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.5.1

I recently changed my desktop to a new one. Installed Android studio and pulled my project from remote. I have all the SDKs and SDK tools in the new android studio 3.5.1. But when I try to build project it fails at gradle sync. The error I get is:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: wear
```

Here are some details that I think are important.

Android plug-in version: 2.3.3 (I have to use it)
gradle version: 4.6

Inside gradle wrapper.properties I have this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

In my wear module build.gradle, i have this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "A.B.C.D"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1252
        versionName "1.2.52"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
//    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1"

    //    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':XYZ')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried the following and none worked:

1. Made sure my JAVA home is pointing to JDK8
2. Several times invalidated the cache and restarted
3. Made sure that gradle plug in and gradle version are correct in project structure
4. Also uninstalled and installed android studio several times.

not sure what is going on but i am just not able to sync it. I am suspecting that the gradle is not properly downloaded and recognized by Android studio. Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

case 1: gradle is not installed :-
you can download the wrapper and point to this in $projectroot/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and just do ./gradlew and check what the error is coming, most probably the error may come due to proxy 
 `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-bin.zip`

case 2: gradle is already intalled:-
just run the ./gradlew clean assemble in console and check the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only solution that worked for me was to switch to Android Studio 3.4